# HTTP 404 Not Found Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS Content-Type: application/json Vary: Accept { "detail": "Not found." }

Tags: python

Does anyone know how can I successfully solve this am getting detail not found error and am trying to get object using ModelView set and raw query
this is my class
class jointtableapi(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
queryset = JoinStudentPadTable.objects.raw('SELECT   regno, first_name, last_name, school_name,collection_date, last_collected, served_by  FROM fulalapp_studentregistrationdetails INNER JOIN fulalapp_studentpadcollectiondetails ON  fulalapp_studentregistrationdetails.id = fulalapp_studentpadcollectiondetails.regno_id')
serializer_class = JoinStudentPadTableSerializer
lookup_field = 'regno_id'
and the url
path('padcollectionjoin-detail/<regno_id>/', jointtableapi.as_view({'get':'retrieve'}), name='padcollectionjoin-detail')
am getting the detail not found error
My Models
from datetime import datetime
from pyexpat import model
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

def user_directory_path(instance, filename):
return 'img/{0}'.format(filename)

## Create your models here.

class StudentRegistrationDetails(models.Model):

```
student_status = (
    ('present', 'Present'),
    ('absent', 'Absent'),
)

#student details
regno = models.CharField(max_length=30)
first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank = True, verbose_name = 'First Name')
last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank = True, verbose_name = 'Last Name')
dob = models.DateField(verbose_name = 'Date Of Birth')
county = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank = True, verbose_name = 'County')
constituency = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank = True, verbose_name = 'Constituency')
school_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank = True, verbose_name = 'School Name')
grade = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank = True, verbose_name = 'Class/Grade')
dom = models.DateField(verbose_name = 'Date Of Menstruation')
photoid = models.ImageField(null = True, blank = True)
status = models.CharField(max_length=11, choices=student_status, default='present')
created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

#parent details
parent_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank = True, verbose_name = 'Parent/Guardian Name')
phoneno = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank = True, verbose_name = 'Phone Number')

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.regno)

class Meta:
    verbose_name_plural = "Student Registration Details"
```

class StudentPadCollectionDetails(models.Model):

```
collection_date = models.DateField(default=datetime.now, verbose_name='Collection Date')
last_collected = models.DateField(verbose_name='Last collection Date')
served_by = models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name='Served BY')
regno = models.ForeignKey("StudentRegistrationDetails", related_name='pad_collection' , verbose_name=("Student ID"), on_delete=models.CASCADE)


def _str_(self):
    return str(self.regno)

class Meta:
    verbose_name_plural = 'Student Pad Collection Details'
```

class JoinStudentPadTable(models.Model):
regno = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=30)
first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank = True, verbose_name = 'First Name')
last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank = True, verbose_name = 'Last Name')
school_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank = True, verbose_name = 'School Name')
collection_date = models.DateField(default=datetime.now, verbose_name='Collection Date')
last_collected = models.DateField(verbose_name='Last collection Date')
served_by = models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name='Served BY')

```
def _str_(self):
    return str(self.regno)

class Meta:
    verbose_name_plural = 'Joint Student Pad Collection Details'
```